# Binding string concatenation for ListBoxItem

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a listbox and I want to show two properties from my object.
For one property it is pretty easy:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
     <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Name} "></TextBlock>                                        
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

However I would like something like

`Name - GroupName`  not just Name...

I know that it is easy, but I am confused. I don't know how to add two textblocks into the same level of the XAML hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this a couple of ways. One is with a `MultiBinding` and a `StringFormat`

```
<TextBlock>
  <TextBlock.Text>
    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} - {1}">
        <Binding Path="Name" />
        <Binding Path="GroupName" />
    </MutliBinding>
  </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

The second is option is to set the root element of your `DataTemplate` to something that can have more than one child, like a `StackPanel` and have to `TextBlock` controls each bound to the appropriate value.

```
<DataTemplate>
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
    <TextBlock Text=" - " />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=GroupName}" />
  </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

I prefer the first option.

Comment: You can also use a TextBlock instead of a StackPanel (a bit cleaner in my opinion): `<TextBlock><Run Text="..."/><Run Text="..."/></TextBlock>`

Comment: @H.B. I always forget `Run` is bindable in 4.0; out of habit I still think in panels.